# No shrinking while screen resolution is reduced CSS /HTML

Tags: html, css

Probably a newbie question but I would like my div and its contents to stay exactly as they are when the screen resolution is reduced (i.e. horizontal scroll bar will appear at the bottom).

I would also like to know how you would stop the contents of the page from stretching when its above the maximum size.

Hope this makes sense.

```
<style>
#header_container {
background: #d1d4fa;
height: 4.5em;
}

#header_layout {
height: 8.5em;
background: #edeef9;    
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="header_container"> 
<div class="container">

<div id="header_layout">                                
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, `em` is scalable font size. [Reference](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/).

Use `px` to keep your font of same size regardless of screen size.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a defined width for your containers and elements.

```
#header_container {
  width: 960px;
}
```